# member function cannot be overloaded for input of set iterator and const_iterator (but can for other stl iterators)

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, language-lawyer, overloading

Compiling the following code

```
struct foo {
    int foo(std::set<int>::iterator);
    int foo(std::set<int>::const_iterator);
};
```

I get the following error from gcc (mingw)

```
func.cpp:5:9: error: 'int functor::foo(std::set<int>::const_iterator)' cannot be overloaded
    int foo(std::set<int>::const_iterator);

func.cpp:4:9: error: with 'int functor::foo(std::set<int>::iterator)'
    int foo(std::set<int>::iterator);
```

and I get similar errors from msvc and clang. I would guess that the problem is that they represent the same underlying type
since in std::set, members are const. This seems to be confirmed by the fact that replacing `set` with `vector` causes it to 
comile perfectly fine.

weirdly, when I remove the functions from the struct and put them in the global namespace

```
int foo(std::set<int>::iterator);
int foo(std::set<int>::const_iterator);
```

it compiles without error. This might be due to different overload rules for nonmember functions that I'm unaware of, I'm not sure

So my questions:

- Why exactly is this overload not allowed?
- Why does putting them in the global namespace allow them to compile?

Comment: Did you try defining the non-member functions? That should have given a multiple definition error.

Comment: @juanchopanza you are 100% correct, after doing that there was an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In global scope, these are just declaration of the same function (when both iterator are same type).

```
int foo(std::set<int>::iterator);
int foo(std::set<int>::const_iterator);
```

In class, you cannot declare twice the same method.

If you define the functions:

```
int foo(std::set<int>::iterator) {return 0;}
int foo(std::set<int>::const_iterator) {return 0;} // program is ill formed (when iterator are same type)
```

You break ODR (One Definition Rule) with 2 definitions of the same function (and probably have duplicated symbol error with linker).

Comment: Note that "both iterator are same type" is not necessarily true.